# Azure Data Factory - connect to ADF client via Python SDK without App registration

Tags: python, azure, sdk, azure-data-factory

Is it possible to connect to ADF client via Python SDK without App registration? And if so, how?

I followed this tutorial: [Create an Azure Data Factory using Python](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/quickstart-create-data-factory-python#prerequisites) however they are creating new ADF so they are using App registration. I do not need to create a new one, just use the one that already exists. Is it possible to do so without an App registration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Result is that I have to use the app registration. Second option was to used custom private agent with needed credentials.

Answer (score 1):

The App registration is for your application which is trying to connect to ADF(in your case trying to create the ADF). In most of the cases, you will need a registered app with client id and secret/certificate regardless of whether you are creating a new ADF or connecting to an existing one.

If you application is hosted on an app service you can use managed identity. Once connected, you can do activities like create linked services, datasets or even trigger pipelines.

Since you already have an ADF, you can skip the "Create a data factory" from the link you shared.